# How to create VIEW in side proceudre

Tags: oracle, plsql

While creating a view inside a procedure through error with the below code. But I need to create this view dynamically.
when I try to run the same script with the existing view it's working fine but I need to create view dynamically before the cursor initialization.

`````
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_dashboard_tiles (out_dashboard_tab OUT return_dashboard_arr,
                                                   start_date IN DATE,
                                                   end_date IN DATE
) IS


    lrec                   return_dashboard_report;
    l_num_counter          NUMBER := 0;
--     CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW x AS (
--     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
--    'SELECT
--        COUNT(*) count,
--        CONCAT('Tier ',customer_tier) value,
--         'customer_tier' viewType
--    FROM
--        bi_request
--    WHERE
--        customer_tier is not null
--        AND START_DATE BETWEEN start_date and end_date
--    GROUP BY
--        customer_tier'
--        );
    CURSOR cur_dashboard_data IS
    SELECT
        count,
        value,
        viewType
    FROM
        v_customer_tier
        ;

    TYPE rec_dashboard_data IS
        TABLE OF cur_dashboard_data%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    l_cur_dashboard_data   rec_dashboard_data;
BEGIN
--    My code EXCEPTION
                        dbms_output.put_line('My code');

END;````

while creating a view inside the procedure through error.
when I try to run the same script with existing view it's working fine but I need to create view dynamically before the cursor initialization
`````

Comment: You can not execute ddl in procedure without `execute immediate` and also it should be in `begin` block not in `declare`

Comment: You'd need to have the `create or replace view` inside your `execute immediate`.  If the view doesn't exist when the procedure is created, though, every subsequent reference to the view would need to be through dynamic SQL-- you can't use static SQL in your cursor definition or your subsequent variable declarations.  This is possible but much more complicated.  Why are you trying to dynamically create the view in the first place?  Perhaps you want to define a pipelined table function and/or a function that returns a `REF CURSOR` that you can pass the dates to?

Comment: I agree with Justin. You should tell us why exactly you want to do this. Dynamic sql is best avoided unless absolutely needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like following:

```
Declare
rec_dashboard_data sys_refcursor;
-- other variable declaration
Begin
Execute immediate q'#<your create view sql>#';
Open rec_dashboard_data for 'SELECT
        count,
        value,
        viewType
    FROM
        v_customer_tier';
-- other task
--Exception block
End;
/
```

Cheers!!